# Change background color on scroll not working as intended

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to change the background color of `#section2` to green if scroll poistion is less than 10 and change it to green if scroll position is greater then 10.

Below code doesnt work as intended, how can i fix this [Fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWRWed)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 10) {
            $('#section2').addClass('greeen');
        }
        else {
            $('#section2').addClass('reed');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the other class using [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 10) {
        $('#section2').removeClass('reed').addClass('greeen');
    }
    else {
        $('#section2').addClass('reed').removeClass('greeen');
    }
});
```

Comment: How can we do same if we have property not class inplace

Comment: @Learning :  what you mean by property in this case?

Comment: i mean i dont have class in the actual code but i use property such as `style=background:red;` when i use the above code to change it doesn't work with it rather it works only with class.

Comment: @Learning : Instead of addClass use css('background-color','red') or refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213592/jquery-code-is-not-running/44213624#44213624

Comment: I am exactly using `$('.item').css('background-color','red');` it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 10) {
            $('#section2').removeClass('reed').addClass('greeen');
        }
        else {
            $('#section2').removeClass('green').addClass('reed');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the class `red` when adding `green` and vise-versa

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 10) {
    $('#section2').addClass('green');
     $('#section2').removeClass('red');
  } else {
     $('#section2').removeClass('green');
      $('#section2').addClass('red');
  }
});
```

also there are typo in `red` and `green` (not `reed` and `greeen`)

**Check this snippet**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 10) {
    $('#section2').addClass('green');
     $('#section2').removeClass('red');
  } else {
     $('#section2').removeClass('green');
      $('#section2').addClass('red');
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  padding: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

section.in-view img {
  opacity: 1;
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

.red {
  background: #f00 !important;
}

.green {
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat, excepturi, necessitatibus assumenda id blanditiis quam molestiae voluptates, reiciendis delectus a dolor at. Assumenda voluptatem tenetur officiis perspiciatis, architecto quos!</p>
  <img src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400">
</section>
<section id="section2">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Est laudantium animi eius asperiores magni perspiciatis facere repudiandae nemo provident facilis ipsum, repellat illum unde qui incidunt ea, veniam. Soluta unde, doloremque dolore culpa, repellat tempora iure labore maxime.</p>
  <img src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400">
</section>
<section id="section3">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Quis magni, id, cum odio laborum impedit veritatis, reprehenderit nisi voluptatum ipsum animi itaque officia! Eius magni ipsa animi nostrum placeat, consequuntur nam odit, impedit architecto quod ipsum reiciendis deserunt.</p>
  <img src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400">
</section>
```